# iOS VoiP Push Notifications, XCode background modes not showing required option

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, voip

I would like to enable VoiP Push notifications. To do this, it seems I have to activate the VoiP option in the background modes section of the capabilities tab, as shown below.

[image]

However, my background modes section doesn't offer this option at all, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

My push notifications are not working and I have implemented everything else correctly (I believe). I am just very confused that my background modes section looks different from anything I can find in tutorials/literature, does anyone have an idea? I run Xcode 9.0.

Comment: Are you using callkit ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xcode 9 then You can add it manually.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

[For more details, integrating VOIP with Swift or Objective C code you can refer](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Comment: I need help in voip. can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create VoIP Services Certificate for your app?
[image: voip[1]

Comment: I have the same issue, I created VoIP Services and installed in PC but, VoiP  option not showing in capabilities